# What to do with the [localization] tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

The [localization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localization) tag has 22 questions on a mish-mash of topics. Mostly it's about scoping (we have [scoping](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scoping)), but some are about [language issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization).

This thread is to solicit opinions on what we should do with this tag, and what it should be used for.

I think the main options are:

- to remove it (moderators: is this possible at all?)
- to map it to another tag such as [scoping](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scoping)
- to clearly define a role for this tag and add the tag wiki

If you post an answer, please indicate if it is meant as a concrete votable proposal, or merely as input.

I posted two options below to get started. Feel free to add new ones.

Answer (score 6):

Upvote if you prefer this option:

We should map [localizaton](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localizaton) to [internationalization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internationalization).

We need a tag for localization and internationalization issues such as code captions. "Localization" is an unfortunate name because people will likely keep using it for scoping issues. Therefore, let us come up with a different canonical tag name for localization and internationalization issues and map [localization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localization) to this new name.

Comment: If you have a better idea for a suitable name, post a new answer.

Answer (score 4):

Upvote if you prefer this option:

We should map [localization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localization) to [scoping](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scoping).

"Localization" is much too often understood as scoping, and even if we add a tag wiki explaining that this tag is meant for something else, people will still keep adding it for scoping-related questions.